# Augment reality in mobile web app

Tags: augmented-reality

Can anyone suggest me how can i implement the following mention below:

Augmented reality( Need to be supported to android,ios,windows,blackberry )
1) Need to open camera app
2) There must be overlay for specific details regarding distance from starting point to end point for destination.

Please suggest me any cordova plugin for doing this.

Comment: You could take a look at https://www.layar.com/documentation/layar-sdk/phonegap-layar-plugin/

Comment: Can you please suggest me free sdk's ,and it has to be only hybrid changes no native changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

**1. Use Unity + Vuforia plugin**
Unity and Vuforia both are free softwres that can be downloaded for the PC as wella s Mac. You can use these to compile to any native Android, iOS, Blackberry or windows phones. You might have to do some coding in either C# or JS. But this is minimal and you can get an application up and running in no time.

**2. Using Augmented Reality with Unity + Vuforia**
Unity has small packages called Prefabs. These can be used to directly spawn an AR camera in your scene.

**3. Distance**
Using a metric in Vuforia, you can get the distance of the camera from the target it is tracking. There is a ready-made code available for that.

Have fun !